# Getting an unknown value while trying to sort an array in c programming

Tags: arrays, c, bubble-sort

I am using VS code. I was sorting an array in c using bubble sort method. It seems to sort right, But I am getting number 4 at the end which is not in the array. here is the code and output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bubble_sort(int nums[], int size);

int main() {
    int nums[] = { 101, 201, 111, 23, 41, 33, 1 };
    
    int size = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(int);
    
    int buble = bubble_sort(nums, size);
    
    printf("%d\n", buble);
}

//  defining bubble sort  
int bubble_sort(int nums[], int size) {

    for (int a = 0; a < size - 1; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < size - a - 1; b++) {
            //swapping
            if (nums[b] > nums[b + 1]) {
                nums[b] = nums[b] ^ nums[b + 1];
                nums[b + 1] = nums[b] ^ nums[b + 1];
                nums[b] = nums[b] ^ nums[b + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
    }
}
```

output I am getting:

```
1
23
33
41
101
111
201
4
```

This is the output I am getting. Here, see the last number. It is not there in the array. I have no idea where this number is from. I tried debugging but it is coming from somewhere. Could anyone tell me from where and Why I am getting this number.

Comment: Your `bubble_sort()` function is specified as returning a `int` value ... but it doesn't have a `return` statement!! ... and in `main()` you use the value it returns (??????) and print it. Suggestion: make `bubble_sort()` into `void bubble_sort(int nums[],int size) { ... }`; and **turn on and mind your compiler warnings**.

Comment: What happens if you need to change the underlying type of the array, e.g. to `long long`? Guess, you need to adjust all those `sizeof`s (well, just one here, but you might have more in the future...). You avoid that by `sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums)`, you might want to get used to right from the start.

Comment: General recommendation: You shouldn't do any output in functions that have a totally different task (`bubble_sort` in your case), that prevents your functions from being re-usable (imagine someone, including yourself, wants to use your bubble_sort later on, but outputs something totally different to console – should that output get spoiled by bubble_sort?). Nothing prevents you from doing the output right within main...

Comment: Oh, about not returning anything: Actually, that's legal in C (in contrast to C++, where that immediately invokes undefined behaviour), but if you then *read* the value returned (implicitly) you *do* invoke UB.

Comment: Thank U for your tips. Actually i was doing this bubble sort for returning the highest values of the array. That is why i made the return type as int instead og void. I understood my mistake now. Thanku so much

Comment: @NAVANEETHJNAIR BTW: if you just need to find the highest value of the array, you don't need any sorting at all.

Comment: @NAVANEETHJNAIR what do you expect `printf("%d\n",buble);` to print?

Comment: swapping by xoring is not a good idea. It is both simpler and more efficient to use a temporary variable: `{ int temp = nums[b]; nums[b] = nums[b + 1]; nums[b + 1] = temp; }`

Comment: actually i was just returning the highest value. That means the last value of sorted array. I was just returning it. that is why I printed it

Comment: The reason Y I am not using a third variable to swap is that it will takes more bits. Butif you swap with XOR operator it wont waste bits

Comment: I dont know how to find the highest value of an array without sorting. is there any better way

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make sense.

```
printf("%d\n",buble);
```

You're printing the return value of the `bubble_sort` function, but it doesn't have a `return` statement, so you don't know what that is going to return.

You should be compiling with the `-Wall` option. If you do, you'll get warnings about things you're doing wrong, including this one:

```
bubble.c: In function ‘bubble_sort’:
bubble.c:33:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

It's saying "You have a function that wants to return a value, and you have no `return` statement."

Comment: Thank U for replying. But a question. Why is it not printing any numbers in main function. In main function also there is no return statement. Hoping a reply

Comment: You're printing the numbers in the array in the `bubble_sort` function. In the `main` function, you're printing one number, the return value of the `bubble_sort` function, which is meaningless. So `bubble_sort` prints the values, and then `main` prints the return value of the function, which happens to be "4" in your test run, but could be anything. Don't print the return value of the `bubble_sort` function because it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Okay i understood. But that was not what i was asking. I am not giving any return statement in main function. Both bubble sort function and main function has int return type. Then why is it only printing the return value of bubble sort but not the main?

Comment: It is printing the return value of `bubble_sort` because you told it to. You assigned the return value of `bubble_sort` with this line: `int buble = bubble_sort(nums,size);`.  Then, you told it to print that value with `printf("%d\n",buble);`.  The program is doing what you told it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're using loop inside `buble_sort` function to print the output on the screen. You don't have to set return type to `int` or store its return value in a new variable which will take extra space in memory.

Since your function does not have a return value and you've prototyped return type as `int`, it is possibly printing the size of `int` (which is 4 byte).

I suggest you to change below lines :

```
int bubble_sort(int nums[], int size);

int buble = bubble_sort(nums,size);   

int bubble_sort(int nums[],int size){
```

to this

```
void bubble_sort(int nums[], int size);    

bubble_sort(nums,size);

void bubble_sort(int nums[],int size){
```

and delete below

```
printf("%d\n",buble);
```

Comment: Is it possible to initialize the function's return type as void and define the function's return type as int. it is showing error for me

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've edited the answer.